# Syntax error in SQL Procedure to create users and grant permissions

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone point out why I'm getting a syntax error? Whenever I try to input it into a console, I get an error of syntax for the "expre2", which I don't get because it seems to be fine:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_User`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `add_User`(IN `p_Name` VARCHAR(45), IN `p_Passw` VARCHAR(200), IN NIF INT(12))
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_HOST` CHAR(14) DEFAULT '@\'localhost\'';
    SET `p_Name` := CONCAT('\'', REPLACE(TRIM(`p_Name`), CHAR(39), CONCAT(CHAR(92), CHAR(39))), '\''),
    `p_Passw` := CONCAT('\'', REPLACE(`p_Passw`, CHAR(39), CONCAT(CHAR(92), CHAR(39))), '\'');
    SET @`sql` := CONCAT('CREATE USER ', `p_Name`, `_HOST`, ' IDENTIFIED BY ', `p_Passw`);
    PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`sql`;
    EXECUTE `stmt`;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    SET @`expre` := CONCAT('GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON trabalho.ver_assist TO ', `p_Name`);
PREPARE `stmt2` FROM @`expre`;
EXECUTE `stmt2`;
DEALLOCATE `stmt2`;
    SET @`expre2` := CONCAT('GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON trabalho.ver_saidas TO ', `p_Name`);
PREPARE `stmt3` FROM @`expre2`;
EXECUTE `stmt3`;
DEALLOCATE `stmt3`;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
END$$
```

I really don't see why it's not working...

Comment: Please update your question with the exact error message you receive from MySQL

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`stmt2`;
    SET @`expre2` := CONCAT('GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON trabalho.ver' at line 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are [missing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/deallocate-prepare.html) a `PREPARE` in `DEALLOCATE stmt2` and `DEALLOCATE stmt3` as well. Please find below the corrected query:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_User`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `add_User`(IN `p_Name` VARCHAR(45), IN `p_Passw` VARCHAR(200), IN NIF INT(12))
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_HOST` CHAR(14) DEFAULT '@\'localhost\'';
    SET `p_Name` := CONCAT('\'', REPLACE(TRIM(`p_Name`), CHAR(39), CONCAT(CHAR(92), CHAR(39))), '\''),
    `p_Passw` := CONCAT('\'', REPLACE(`p_Passw`, CHAR(39), CONCAT(CHAR(92), CHAR(39))), '\'');
    SET @`sql` := CONCAT('CREATE USER ', `p_Name`, `_HOST`, ' IDENTIFIED BY ', `p_Passw`);
    PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`sql`;
    EXECUTE `stmt`;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    SET @`expre` := CONCAT('GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON trabalho.ver_assist TO ', `p_Name`);
PREPARE `stmt2` FROM @`expre`;
EXECUTE `stmt2`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt2`;
    SET @`expre2` := CONCAT('GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON trabalho.ver_saidas TO ', `p_Name`);
PREPARE `stmt3` FROM @`expre2`;
EXECUTE `stmt3`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt3`;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
END$$
```

Comment: @user10280626 happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your set statements are incorrect you have to select for example SET @sql := (select CONCAT('CREATE USER ', `p_Name`, `_HOST`, ' IDENTIFIED BY ', `p_Passw`));

and 2 of your deallocate are incorrect the syntax is deallocate prepare something

And there's an awful lot of unnecessary backticks in there.

Comment: The first one seems fine though. This is the error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`stmt2`;
    SET @`expre2` := CONCAT('GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON trabalho.ver' at line 14